# Automatic shutdown at specific gpu/cpu temperature in linux

Tags: linux, gpu, temperature, lm-sensors

How to configure `linux` or `lm-sensors` or etc. to automatic shutdown at specific `GPU` or `CPU` temperature?

Answer (score 0):

`Mate display manager` has a sensor applet that have this option.
You can set a command to execute at a specific temperature.